# Team Foundation server (TFS) restore, Missing services?

Tags: service, administration

I'm testing out the backup and restore of TFS, before migrating to it for our source control. Problem is, I'm getting confused with *restore* part of the msdn documentation.

In particular, the part where we are required to update the service accounts (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252458.aspx#UpdateAccounts).

> You must update the service account
>   for Team Foundation Server
>   (TFSService)

My assumptions are that by the term *services* they mean windows services. Based on this, I'm assuming that when they talk about *TFSService*, this is the name of the service we need to locate.

So the problem comes when I try and locate *TFSService* in the services.msc dialog to find out what user account its running under and therefore need to update. It doesn't seem to exist!

So my questions are:

1. Is this service the right one I need to look for, and if it is, are they any reasons why I wouldn't have it.
2. Am I understanding this section of the documentation correctly? I.e. that I need to find the account that the TFS server service runs under, and use the command line specified to update it?

I'm using TFS 2010 on a VM for testing if this helps!

Thanks,

Andy.

** Update **

Just looking at the TFS console, is the service account that we need to update the same as the service account listed under the Application Tier node?

If so, does the link 'Reapply account' do the same as the command line in the MSDN document?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like *Reapply Account* in the TFS console does exactly what the command line does (+ checks application pools and TFSJobAgent), so at least I'm happy I'm performing the steps now.

As to why they haven't mentioned this easier way to perform the sets in the documentation? Perhaps a last minute release feature?

I guess as for my question 1, perhaps there are no windows services for TFS? Am I just getting mixed up with terminology?

Hope this helps someone anyway!

Andy.